# How to use interface type as a model in mgo (Go)?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Suppose you have a workflow that consists of multiple embedded nodes of different types. Since nodes are of different types, I thought of using Golang interfaces here and came up with following:

```
type Workflow struct {
   CreatedAt time.Time
   StartedAt time.Time
   CreatedBy string
   Nodes []Node
}

type Node interface {
  Exec() (int, error)
}

type EmailNode struct {
   From string
   To string
   Subject string
   Body string
}

type TwitterNode struct {
   Tweet string
   Image []byte
}

func (n *EmailNode) Exec() (int, error){
   //send email
   return 0, nil
}

func (n *TwitterNode) Exec() (int, error) {
   //send tweet
   return 0, nil
}
```

These workflows are stored in MongoDB and I have sample seed data in it. Using mgo, when I try to find a workflow (given its ID):

```
w = &Workflow{}
collection.FindID(bson.ObjectIdHex(id)).One(w)
```

I get the error - value of type bson.M is not assignable to type Node.

It also feels a bit weird to me that how would mgo unmarshal embedded Node documents into a Go struct without any type information. May be I need to look at the problem from another point of view.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use an interface in a document for the reason you noted. The decoder has no information about the type to create.

One way to handle this is to define a struct to hold the type information:

```
type NodeWithType struct {
   Node Node `bson:"-"`
   Type string
}

type Workflow struct {
   CreatedAt time.Time
   StartedAt time.Time
   CreatedBy string
   Nodes []NodeWithType
}
```

Implement the SetBSON function on this type. This function should decode the type string, create a value of the correct type based on that string and unmarshal to that value.

```
func (nt *NodeWithType) SetBSON(r bson.Raw) error {
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how the setBSON function would be implemented? I don't know how to decode the type string.

Answer (score 7):

Following Simon Fox's answer regarding the implementation of `SetBSON`, here is a more precise answer.

Let's take the original piece of code:

```
type Workflow struct {
   CreatedAt time.Time
   StartedAt time.Time
   CreatedBy string
   Nodes     []Node
}

type Node interface {
  Exec() (int, error)
}

type EmailNode struct {
   From    string
   To      string
   Subject string
   Body    string
}

type TwitterNode struct {
   Tweet string
   Image []byte
}

func (n *EmailNode) Exec() (int, error){
   //send email
   return 0, nil
}

func (n *TwitterNode) Exec() (int, error) {
   //send tweet
   return 0, nil
}
```

What you want to do now is: once you unmarshal the BSON object from Mongo, you want to be able to know if each node is either an `EmailNode` or a `TwitterNode`.

As you are storing the nodes as a `Node` interface, mgo has no way to know what struct to implement, so you have to tell it explicitly. Here comes `SetBSON`.

In your example, the problem comes from this `Workflow.Nodes`, which is a slice of `Node` interface. As it is a simple slice, the best is that you create a custom type that mgo will be able to call when unmarshalling the BSON:

```
type NodesList []Node

// The updated Workflow struct:
type Workflow struct {
    CreatedAt time.Time
    StartedAt time.Time
    CreatedBy string
    Nodes     NodesList
}
```

Now, you can implement `SetBSON` on this `NodesList` and describe how it works. Please note that as you are using a pointer, you can define what is contained inside the variable:

```
// Note that you must use a pointer to the slice
func (list *NodesList) SetBSON(raw raw.BSON) error {
    // Now you need to create the objects according to your
    // own domain logic and what's contained inside "raw":
    if raw.something {
        *list = append(*list, &TwitterNode{})
    } else {
        *list = append(*list, &EmailNode{})
    }

    return nil
}
```