# How do I use bson.SetBSON or bson.Raw?

Tags: go, bson, mgo

Possibly related: [How to use interface type as a model in mgo (Go)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26039580/how-to-use-interface-type-as-a-model-in-mgo-go)

I have a struct like so:

```
type Game struct {
    ID       bson.ObjectId
    Type     string
    Location string
    Details  interface{}
}

type FeudDetails struct {
    ...
}

type TriviaDetails struct {
    ...
}

type BingoDetails struct {
    ...
}
```

I want to use the `Type` field of `Game` to unserialize `Details` into a specific type (like an instance of `FeudDetails` or `BingoDetails`). It would still be an `interface{}` in `Game`, but then I could do this:

```
feudDetails, ok := game.Details.(FeudDetails)
if ok {
    // we know this is a Feud game, and we have the details
    feudDetails.Round++
}
```

[The docs](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#Raw) say that "it is possible to unmarshal or marshal values partially" using `bson.Raw`, but they don't provide any examples I've been able to find.

I've tried using:

```
func (game *Game) SetBSON(r bson.Raw) error {
    err := r.Unserialize(game)
    if err != nil {
        return nil
    }
    games[game.Type].LoadDetails(game)  // this calls a function based on the Type to
                                        // create a concrete value for that game.
    return nil
}
```

I get a *(ahem)* stack overflow here. I assume this is because `r.Unserialize` is recursively calling `SetBSON`.

My goal is to use standard unserializing on all fields *except* `Details`, and then be able to use `game.Type` to determine how to process `Details`.  If I do something like this:

```
type GameDetails interface{}

type Game struct {
    ...
    Details GameDetails
}

func (details *GameDetails) SetBSON(r bson.Raw) error {
    // game isn't defined
    games[game.Type].LoadDetails(r, details)
}
```

then how can I access the outer `Type` field to know which game type to unserialize it to?

I'll also accept the answer "you're doing it all wrong, and a better pattern in Go is XYZ..."

**EDIT:** I also tried deserializing normally, and then casting the `interface{}` version of `Details` using `game.Details.(FeudDetails)`, but the conversion failed. I guess I can't do it that way because the underlying type after unserialization is *not* a `FeudDetails` but rather probably `map[string]interface{}`.

**EDIT 2:** I thought I'd be clever and pre-populate an object with the right types when retrieving from the database (`game := Game{Details: FeudDetails: {}}` prior to calling `db...One(&game)`) but my trickery did not work:

```
DEBU[Mar 31 22:19:09.442] Caching show                 gid=5e814448ef5b9858b7ff4e57
TRAC[Mar 31 22:19:09.442] Before database call         dtype=main.FeudDetails
TRAC[Mar 31 22:19:09.446] After database call          dtype=bson.M
```

Comment: I think I found a possible solution (it's JSON, but it probably works the same for BSON). I'll adapt it to my code and if it works I'll post it as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53453782/unmarshal-dynamic-json-based-on-a-type-key

Answer (score 1):

## Ignore `Details` during (un)marshalling

Change the definition of `Game` so `bson` doesn't try to do anything with the `Details` field:

```
type Game struct {
    ...
    Details interface{} `json:"details" bson:"-"`
}
```

## Unmarshal `Details` manually

```
func (game *Game) SetBSON(r bson.Raw) error {
    // Unmarshall everything except Details
    type tempGame Game
    err := r.Unmarshal((*tempGame)(game))  // this is necessary to prevent recursion
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    // Get the raw data for Details
    var d struct {
        Details bson.Raw
    }
    if err := r.Unmarshal(&d); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    gameType, ok := games[game.Type]
    if ok {
        // Use individual processing based on game Type
        game.Details, err = gameType.LoadDetails(d.Details)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        // fmt.Sprintf("%T", game.Details) => main.FeudDetails
    }
    return nil
}
```

## Marshal `Details` manually

As far as I can tell, the only way to get `bson` to *include* `Details` after we told it to omit it in the original struct, is to create a whole other structure, copy the data over one by one, and use that type in `GetBSON`. It seems like there must be a better way.